# reinterpret_cast vs c style cast

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c-style cast vs reinterpret_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427107/c-style-cast-vs-reinterpret-cast)

What is the difference between:

```
A* pA = new B;

B* p1 = (B*)pA;
B* p2 = reinterpret_cast<B*>(pA);
```

Are they both identical ways of doing the same thing? Is there any reason to choose one over the other? Should the "C style" cast be avoided in C++ code?

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is not the right cast for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A C-style cast is equivalent to the first of the following that succeeds:

- a `const_cast`
- a `static_cast`
- a `static_cast` followed by `const_cast`
- a `reinterpret_cast`
- a `reinterpret_cast` followed by `const_cast`

So in certain situations, a C-style cast will have the same effect as `reinterpret_cast` but they are not equivalent. Since a C-style cast is basically a "oh, just cast it however you can" cast, it's better to prefer the more specific casts.

For your example, it is preferable to use a `static_cast` since you know the actual type of the derived object. When you don't, use `dynamic_cast`.