# Is it possible to convert an integer pointer to the actual integer located at that memory location?

Tags: c++

Normally, we declare variables like this in C++:

```
int exampleInteger;
```

What if I have a pointer to the address of an integer? Can I declare an integer located at a certain memory address?

```
int* exampleIntegerPtr = (int*) 0x457FB;
int exampleInteger = *exampleIntegerPtr;
```

Unfortunately, exampleInteger in the second example isn't like exampleInteger in the first example. The second example creates a new variable that has the same value as the integer located at exampleIntegerPtr. Is it possible to somehow grab the actual integer located at exampleIntegerPtr?

Comment: Please try compiling your example, `int* aPtr = 0x457FB;`.

Comment: you can just use *aPtr in whatever calculation you want to use the integer in. Or declare a new integer and copy that value into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using *references*, like this:

```
int &a(*aPtr);
```

At this point, any changes done to the `int` stored at `aPtr` will be reflected in `a`:

```
*aPtr = 123;
cout << a << endl; // 123 is printed
*aPtr = 456;
cout << a << endl; // 456 is printed
```

Of course in order for this to work you need to ensure that the constant `0x457FB` indeed represents a valid address available for reading and writing by your program.

Comment: Wow. Thank you! I was almost sure that it would be impossible.

Comment: You are welcome! In case you'd like to learn more about C++ references, [Wikipedia has an article on them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)).

Comment: One more question. I get how `int& a = *aPtr;` works but how does `int &a(*aPtr);` work? You're using brackets on a primitive declaration?

Comment: @user2465415 It's the same thing. I prefer the syntax with parentheses because it is easier to distinguish it from assignments.

Answer (score 1):

As [dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16995336/1708801) said you can use references to accomplish what you desire. I would add one things to this, since we are using C++ you should prefer [reinterpret_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)  over `C style` casts since you are being explicit about your intention and they are easier to find and stand out more, this [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427107/c-style-cast-vs-reinterpret-cast) goes into this in more detail. The code would look as follows:

```
int* exampleIntegerPtr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(0x457FB);
int &exampleInteger = *exampleIntegerPtr;
```