# Why wont this C++ code compile?

Tags: c++, gcc, types, iostream, endianness

I've been tasked with setting up a Debian server that will provide a service using [TTK](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aberger/software/TTK.html) (trigger toolkit).

However, the software seems to be from 1997, and unmaintained, and wont compile with GCC (`g++`) by default (v4.7.2).

Some of the errors originated from not specifying the `std` namespace, and I've fixed those.

However, I'm having problems with a class that seems to be included in the software for hardware compatibility, specifically, its `read` functions.

The class, from what I can understand, is supposed to abstract endianness of the hardware (or something of a similar nature):

```
public:
    Architecture()
    {
      short y = 256;
      short *x=&y;
      alpha_byte_ordering = ( *( (char*) (x) + 1) ) == 1 ? 1 : 0;
      if (alpha_byte_ordering)
        fprintf(stderr, "Architecture: detected alpha byte ordering.\n");
      else fprintf(stderr, "Architecture: detected non-alpha byte ordering.\n");
    }

    int read(istream &is, short *s)
    {
      if (!is.read(s, sizeof(short))) return 0;
      if (!alpha_byte_ordering) reverse_byte_order(s);
      return 1;
    }
```

There are many other overloaded `read` functions, and they all spit out errors such as this one:

```
Architecture.H: In member function ‘int Architecture::read(std::istream&, short int*)’:
Architecture.H:31:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_istream<char>::read(short int*&, long unsigned int)’
```

It seems as if this code was ignorant of the C++ standard which I think specifies that `istream::read` should accept a character array (`char *`), not varying types such as `short *` and `double *` (I actually read that [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/), not in the standard).

Am I interpreting this code incorrectly? Has this aspect of the standard changed since 1997? Or was this code simply non-functional to begin with (I highly doubt this since there are papers written about it)?

Lastly, how can I fix this? Casting `s` to `char *` C-style seems to remove the errors but I'm not sure whether it fixes the problem or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) function want's a pointer to the character type (i.e. `char*` in your case) as first argument. You need to use `reinterpret_cast` to cast the pointer correctly.

Like

```
is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(s), sizeof(*s))
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick. However I thought `reinterpret_cast` was only used for polymorphic types, and that C-style casts were enough for fundamental types and pointers...

Comment: @Yannbane `reinterpret_cast` is the C++ way of doing C-style casts, while `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast` is for polymorphic types.

Comment: @Yannbane see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427107/c-style-cast-vs-reinterpret-cast) for a detailed explanation