# C++ gives strange error during structure initialization with an array inside

Tags: c++

I try to compile very simple code:

```
struct T {
    int a[3];
    int b;
    int c;
};

int main() {
    const int as[3] = { 5, 6, 7, };
    const T t {
        as, 2, 3,
    };
    return 0;
}
```

But it gives me very strange errors:

```
t.cpp: In function 'int main()':
t.cpp:11:5: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
     };
     ^
```

As from what I understand the compiler wants me to initialize everything in one single place. How do I initialize fields separately and then use them during initiliazation the structure later?

Comment: `std::array` to the rescue.

Comment: You can't do that with plain arrays. Are you allowed to modify `T`?

Comment: @juanchopanza I would like to have only `costs` as possible in my code and to avoid mutation only for initialization of the object, this is my principle.. So The question here is to initialize a const object.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy I think that what juanchopanza  is asking is if you can change the member `a` ot the structure `T` to be of a different type? For example `std::array<int, 3> a;`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh, excuse me then. Yes, I can change it to everything, this is my own structure.

Comment: As a side note, the C solution would be to put the initializer list inside a macro, then use that macro during initialization. Not really something I'd recommend in C++ (since you would be using std::array instead).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Arrays are neither copy-constructible nor copy-assignable. If you have access to C++11 and newer, you could use `std::array`.

```
#include <array>

struct T {
    std::array<int, 3> a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

int main() {
    const std::array<int,3> as = { 5, 6, 7, };
    const T t {
        as, 2, 3,
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise you will have to roll a loop and copy the elements individually.

Comment: Or you could use nested braced initializer lists

Answer (score 11):

C++ arrays are not copy constructible, so compilation will fail. However,

```
struct T {
    int a[3];
    int b;
    int c;
};

int main() {
    const T t {
        {5, 6, 7, }, 2, 3,
    };
    return 0;
}
```

is an alternative, although it does discard the explicit `as` variable.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyConstructible

Comment: This solution though, is unrealistic when it comes to larger arrays.

Answer (score 2):

> As from what I understand the compiler wants me to initialize everything in one single place.

This is because *array types decay into pointer types* and then the compiler tries to assign a pointer to an array type.

> How do I initialize fields separately and then use them during initiliazation the structure later?

You can use pointer types in the structure (which I would not advise). Or you can use container classes instead (STL).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this, but it assumes your `T t` data is not really const as I remove its constness with `const_cast<>()`

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

struct T {
    int a[3];
    int b;
    int c;
};

int main() {
    const int as[3] = { 5, 6, 7, };

    const T t {
        {0}, 2, 3,
    };

    memcpy( reinterpret_cast< void* >( const_cast< int* > ( t.a ) ), 
            reinterpret_cast< const void* >( as ), 
            std::min( sizeof t.a, sizeof as ) );

    printf( "t.a: '%d, %d, %d'\n", t.a[0], t.a[1], t.a[2] );
    return 0;
}
```

If you data `T t` is not actually const, you can do it without the `const_cast<>()`

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

struct T {
    int a[3];
    int b;
    int c;
};

int main() {
    const int as[3] = { 5, 6, 7, };

    T t {
        {0}, 2, 3,
    };

    memcpy( reinterpret_cast< void* >( t.a ),
            reinterpret_cast< const void* >( as ), 
            std::min( sizeof t.a, sizeof as ) );

    printf( "t.a: '%d, %d, %d'\n", t.a[0], t.a[1], t.a[2] );
    return 0;
}
```

I am adding the `reinterpret_cast<>()` because `memcpy()` requires a `void*`

> function 
>   void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
>
> Copies the values of num bytes from the location pointed to by source directly to the memory block pointed to by destination.
>   http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/

I am also doing `std::min( sizeof t.a, sizeof as )` to avoid override any data it should not in case the source array is way bigger than expected.

And finally, `{0}` is initializing by default the destine array with zeros. It could also be `{}` to not initialize anything and let the default values to be trash memory/random data.

References:

1. [When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)
2. [Should I use static_cast or reinterpret_cast when casting a void* to whatever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310451/should-i-use-static-cast-or-reinterpret-cast-when-casting-a-void-to-whatever)
3. [When to use reinterpret_cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573294/when-to-use-reinterpret-cast)
4. [Should I use a C++ reinterpret_cast over a C-style cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427107/should-i-use-a-c-reinterpret-cast-over-a-c-style-cast)
5. [Use of min and max functions in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632145/use-of-min-and-max-functions-in-c)